# Variable becomes NULL in IF statement

Tags: php

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
    $results_array[$row['post_id']] = $row;   

    $arr = array($row[2] => $row[3]); 

    $location = trim($arr[cp_check_where_to_show_video]);
    $video    = trim($arr[cp_embed_video]);

    echo $video;

    if($location=='Video of the Day')
    { 
        echo $location."\n";
        echo "---";
        echo $video; 
        echo "---";  
    } 
}

Output:
    Video Text
    Video of the Day
    -------
    NULL
```

Here's the thing. Suppose I have the code above, the 'videos' were derived from the database. So far, i'm having no problem with my queries until I added the if statement.
The first echo outputs the expected results, but inside the if statement "video" becomes NULL. I could get in the if statement and output anything except for the $video.

Could someone please tell what went wrong or could possibly be wrong with the statements above? Weird.

Comment: What is the `condition`? That may be the problem.

Comment: nope. the conditions are alright. looking at the code above. I could output "RawR!" but not the $video.

Comment: +1 to above. If you're accidentally unsetting $video in condition, you will end up with null. A way to test this is to run echo $video *after* the IF and see if it's still null.

Comment: Only other explination is that you have $Video (or some other case / spelling error inside the if). Eitherway, more code required.

Comment: Still looks good. Can you confirm you have copied "$video" correctly (all lower case, smae spelling etc).

Comment: Are you sure there are no `null` values in your database? They wouldn't print at all with echo, but with your var_dump they will.

Comment: @Robbie: $video is correct..

james: there are no null values in the database. Tried var_dump and still returns NULL and the thing is I could echo $video before the IF statement. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Really a comment, but adding code so putting in here)

Debug solution 1: Add error reporting; just before the while, add

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

and see what that give you.

Debug solution 2:

Could be a case of "Editor inserted wierd character that I can't see". Suggestion is to TOTALLY delete the lines inside the if statement (select entire line, hit delete), as well as the lines that reference $video, and retype them manually (no copy / paste). Hidden characters do happen - and the only solution I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

Frequently, people forget and use `=` instead of `==` in the comparison.  It sets the condition to `true` and if `$video` is in the condition, you may be accidentally be setting the `$video` to `null`.

Comment: $video is not used in the if condition... and so far i still don't have a clue what went wrong. grr..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but it could be like this.

The first time it echos the $video but doesn't go inside the `if`.
Second time it is NULL so doesn't echo anything but goes inside the if `var_dumps` NULL

**EDIT**

For example put `echo '----';` above your `echo $video;` to check if the output is something like

```
----
video text
----
Video of the Day
NULL
```

If you have something like

```
----
video text
Video of the Day
NULL
```

then that is a total mystery to me.

Comment: thanks for the reply.. i could echo $location though.but not $video.

Comment: what I meant is, since this is running in a loop, are you sure the returns are coming from the same instance? Put `echo '--------------';` above your `echo $video;` and try?

Comment: when i added echo '---' above and below the echo $video..<br/>
i get '------ NULL' >.<

Comment: ah no mate, remove the `echo "---";` s from where you have them right now, and add one before the first `echo $video;` which is above the if condition.